# If statements messing up with eventReactive

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, shiny-reactivity

I don't know if I'm missing some basic fact about Shiny here (which is likely as I'm new to R) but I have a chunk of code which is not working and I do not know why.

I have a database, and  I have a basic Shiny app that makes a graph out of it. The user can select any of the variables in the database, and one value among the possible values of one of the variables I have.
For this I use two selectInputs. I have and update button too, which is linked to some eventReactives in the server function. This is inside a sidebar. 
Aside of that I have a mainPanel in which the created graph appears (or it used to).

This is my app:

```
library("shiny")
library("tidyverse")


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(" Gráficas según tipo de delito"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Seleccionando una variable de la lista muestra gráficas para cada delito."),

      selectInput(
        inputId ="variable_graf",
        label="Seleccione la variable", 
        choices = database %>% names(),
        selected = "PUDAHUEL"
      ),

      selectInput(
        inputId = "delito_graf" ,
        label="Seleccione delito", 
        choices = database$nombre_delito %>% unique(),
        selected="hurto"
      ),
      actionButton(
        inputId = "boton_graf",
        label=" Pulse para actualizar la gráfica con los datos seleccionados"
      )

      ),
    mainPanel( 
      plotOutput("graph"),
      dataTableOutput("base_mostrar")
    )
  )
  )

server <- function(input, output) {

  shiny_database<-eventReactive(
    input$boton_graf,
    {
      df <- database %>% filter( nombre_delito==input$delito_graf)
      df <- df %>% group_by( !!as.name(input$variable_graf ) ) %>% count()

         }

  )

  graf_por_delito<-eventReactive(
    shiny_database(),
    {
      ggplot(data = shiny_database() , mapping = aes(x = !!as.name(input$variable_graf), y = n)) +
       geom_col()+ggtitle(input$delito_graf %>% paste("por") %>% paste(input$variable_graf))+ theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
    }
  )

  output$graph<-renderPlot({
    graf_por_delito()
  })

  output$base_mostrar<-renderDataTable({shiny_database()})

}


    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Everythink was working smoothly and fine untill I tried to add a new option in one of the selectInputs. 
This option requires to create a new dataset, and a new ggplot. 
For so, I created two if statements inside my eventReactive() functions.

It didn't work. After trying to debug it I noticed that the problem was not in the code inside my new if statements but in the second if statements by themselves.

If I put the code I had inside one of my eventReactive() functions inside an if statement it works Ok.
But the moment I add a second if statement, even if it's void and the condition for it to be executed is not happening, my graph won't be displayed.

Is there any Shiny's basic concept I am missing here? Are there any straightforward way to overcome this problem?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you're trying to produce a plot it shouldn't be inside a eventReactive() It should be inside a renderPlot(). Try `output$shiny_graph <- renderPlot({  data <- shiny_database() (plot or ggplot using data)   })`

Comment: You should the code with the "uninteresting code wrangling" because it probably is essential to solving the problem. For example, if input$button is a filter then you need to filter the dataset by input$button, which I can't tell if you did or not because there is nothing there. You should paste your entire UI and Server

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your code structure is more straightforward than mine, as I'm using and additional eventReactive() function to build the graph and then I pass is to renderPlot() instead of directly writting ggplot inside de renderPlot(). But in this way, how can I make graph update button reactive? And, even then, i have to be able to create two diferent databases based on the input, for what I need to use if clauses inside my first eventReactive()

Comment: I edited the question providing all code as you suggested. Variable names are in Spanish, I hope it's not too confusing. Anyway, I'm going to edit var names to make them more generic and understandable.

Comment: I really don't think you need to do the second eventReactive(), try getting rid of that and moving the actual plotting to the renderPlot() and saving data <- base_pestaña_graf(). I did something similar to this today, and it worked fine for me.

Comment: I see your point, but even then, when I add two if statements in the first eventReactive() my app stops producing any graph or database, just an empty mainPanel. No error message. This is happening even if the second if statement is void and has a condition that doesn't take place. And I wonder why. Thank you for your help!